# How to get sudo username in python?

Tags: python, unix

I am trying to run my script as below and want access to sudo user running this script.

```
:$sudo -u usergroup script.py
```

So here I am expecting 'usergroup' as output.
What I have tried is,

- getpass: This gives you the actual user and not sudo user

.

```
:$ sudo -u usergroup ipython

In [1]: import getpass

In [2]: getpass.getuser()
Out[2]: 'akshay'
```

- os.getenv

.

```
In [4]: os.getenv("SUDO_USER")
Out[4]: 'akshay'

In [5]: os.getenv("USER")
Out[5]: 'akshay'
```

I am using below python version.

```
In [7]: sys.version
Out[7]: '2.7.11 (default, Apr 25 2016, 09:27:56) \n[GCC 5.2.1 20150902 (Red Hat 5.2.1-2)]'

In [8]:
```

Kindly help here. Could not came across any existing question or solution for it.

Comment: Are you trying to execute commands on the server as sudo? or just getting information about sudo?

Comment: just getting information for logging.

Comment: Don't know what's your question, the code works well.

Comment: `sudo` expands to *switch user and do*. It can be used to execute a command as any other user. The user can be specified using `-u`. Now the default (in case -u is not provided) is `root`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use [`os.geteuid`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.geteuid) to get [effective user id](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_identifier#Effective_user_ID) (euid, used for most access checks).

```
>>> import os
>>> os.geteuid()
0
```

Then, pass the return value to [`pwd.getpwuid`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pwd.html#pwd.getpwuid) to get information about the uid returned:

```
>>> import pwd
>>> pwd.getpwuid(os.geteuid())
pwd.struct_passwd(pw_name='root', pw_passwd='x', ...)
```

Access `pw_name` attribute (or [0]) of the `pwd.getpwuid()` to get username of the effective user.

```
>>> pwd.getpwuid(os.geteuid()).pw_name
'root'
>>> pwd.getpwuid(os.geteuid())[0]
'root'
```

---

To get effective group information, use [`os.getegid`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getgid) + [`grp.getgrgid`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/grp.html#grp.getgrgid).

```
>>> grp.getgrgid(os.getegid())
grp.struct_group(gr_name='root', gr_passwd='x', gr_gid=0, gr_mem=[])
>>> grp.getgrgid(os.getegid()).gr_name
'root'
```

Comment: Perfect solution for my usecase, infact later one liner `pwd.getpwuid(os.geteuid()).pw_name`